# There were some bug on the onResponderRelease function of View.props

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I set some responders of the view.And When I handle the view there are some times when onResponderRelease function can't be called. I don't know  how to solve it. And the view is in the scrollview.

```
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
        return true
    },
    onResponderTerminationRequest:()=>{
        return false
    },
    onResponderTerminate: (evt) => {
        console.log('break');
    },
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: ()=> {
        return true
    },
    onPanResponderMove: (evt,gs)=>{
        console.log('move')
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: (evt,gs)=>{
        console.log('release')
    }
```